# set window.location after wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a callback function that changes

```
window.location.href = url;
```

however, this callback is invoked after checking whether an image exists in a different page (and different domain).
My problem is that IE9 won't let me do the following:

```
        $(testImage)
            .bind("load readystatechange", function (e) {
                if (this.complete || (this.readyState === 'complete' && e.type === 'readystatechange')) {
                    callbackFunction(true);
                }
            })
            .bind("error abort", function () {
                abort();
            })
            .attr("src", testUrl);
```

IE9 WILL however allow me to do this:

```
callbackFunction(true);
```

but as I want to wait and see that my image exists, I need the above to work. (I don't want to change IE settings) Of course, it all works just fine in Chrome.

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: I think I should clarify: "when I say ie9 wont let me do.." I mean that ie9 executes the callback BUT the code inside (changing url) don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE also supports the `load` event on images, you don't **have** to explicitly check the `.readyState` property unless you have another reason you didn't mention.

So it should absolutely be enough to go like

```
$( testImage ).on('load', function( e ) {
    callbackFunction( true );
});
```

Comment: Still will not work, think it is because ie wont allow changing the url in an async call.

Comment: @drbaltar: I can't imagine that. Does this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/bQ7kG/ ?

Comment: yes that works, my page is https btw. Noting a difference between chrome and ie9 on the test page: chrome show alert right when page is loaded while ie requires a button click...

Comment: I think I should clarify: "when I say ie9 wont let me do.." I mean that ie9 executes the callback BUT the code inside (changing url) don't work.